# Избавиться от знаков вопроса в компоненте

Tags: php, битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ошибка, я не знаю где искать. Запуститла проверку сайта - база в кодировке *utf8*, параметры:

> mbstring.func_overload=2 
>   mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8

Файлы компонента *catalog* переконвертировала в *utf8* c помощью скрипта, [описанного в сообществе Bitrix](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/howto/1466.php), задав предварительный путь к папке.

```
define('START_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/components/bitrix/catalog/'); // стартовая папка для поиска
```

Не помогло. Мне главное пока этот шаблон уделать.
файл uni.loc\bitrix\php_interface\after_connect.php

```html
Код
$DB->Query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$DB->Query('SET collation_connection = "utf8_unicode_ci"'); 
$DB->Query('SET Character_set_results="utf8"');//my
```

UPD Возникает ошибка после выполнения инструкции скрипта- переконвертера
[image: Вот здесь ошибка после выполнения скрипта по инструкции]

Comment: Что подразумевается под "уделать шаблон"?

Comment: Этот шаблон стандартный- входит в битрикс, не скопированный в папку шаблона. Далее, мне нужно избавиться от знаков вопросов е=на картинке+ чтобы при детальном просмотре не было знаков вопросов. Как на картинке http://prntscr.com/9jeg89. Что посмотреть lang файлы в компоненте, там вроде русские буквы.... и кодировка utf8.

Comment: Знаки вопроса - это другая кодировка, отличная от той, что в данный момент у страницы. Либо проблема с UTF-8 в БД, либо при подключении к БД устанавливается отличная от UTF-8, либо сайт использует другую, не UTF-8.

Comment: @Rang запустила проверку сайта в админке. База в кодировке utf8. а за данный компонент какие таблицы отвечают( да в принципе, их нет)?

Comment: в настройках сайта указан utf8.

Comment: uni.loc\bitrix\php_interface\after_connect.php

Comment: @RRR, выполняя переход по инструкции, на каком шаге возникли проблемы? Были выполнены все пункты руководства? Запускался скрипт "convert_utf8.php", с каким результатом?

Comment: база стоит в кодировке utf8. я закомментировала error (мне конвертация базы не нужна). Далее,  в данном скрипте (путь выше) задала путь к компоненту каталог (просто думала, что "вопросы" находятся только там для моего компонента, и больше нигде). Запустила скрипт. Ошибок нет. По-новой создала компонент каталог( стандартный, который входит в битрикс), не помогло.

Comment: и программа  UTFCast Express. не помогла, перекодировала component.php

Comment: @RRR, почему , если я скопирую  папку \uni.loc\bitrix\components\bitrix\catalog в папку \uni.loc\bitrix\components\bitrix\catalog2 или \uni.loc\bitrix\components\bitrix\catalog3 . То, если кликаешь в визуальном редакторе на компонент catalog (Знаки вопроса остаются), если кликаешь на catalog2 или catalog3 , то без знаков вопроса и страницы нормально отображаются. Если обратно переименовать catalog3 или catalog2 в catalog , то появляются знаки вопроса. Как исправить, чтобы catalog корректно отбражался.

Comment: @RRR, я не знаком с окружением Битрикс и визуальным редактором, но может дело в кэше браузера или кэшировании со стороны сайта. И не понял это "я закомментировала error (мне конвертация базы не нужна)" и "в данном скрипте (путь выше) задала путь к компоненту каталог (просто думала, что "вопросы" находятся только там для моего компонента, и больше нигде)" - функция Error лишь выводит текст ошибок и не меняет сам функционал скрипта. Скрипт конвертации перекодирует ВСЕ файлы (js, php), относительно корневой дирректории сайта, он не спрашивает названий или путей, в UTF-8.

Comment: Откройте файл `lang/ru/.parameters.php` компонента и посмотрите как там с кодировкой.

Comment: @Rang, большое спасибо, запустила скрипт-конвертер, возникло исключение.

Comment: @u_mulder, большое спасибо. в точку. Я запустила скрипт, возникло исключение , картинка выше.

Comment: Какая-то проблема на стороне js, подгружающего параметры компонентов. Мне кажется проще ручками перекодировать нужные вам файлы, если вы в никсах - то `iconv`

Comment: Да, пришлось, ручками.... А как можно найти тот js , вызывающий исключение?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что заниматься нужно перекодировкой таблицы каталога из базы данных. Если Битрикс-каталог наполняется сторонним модулем, загруженным из магазина, то он может работать в другой кодировке. Я сталкивался с подобным. База может быть в кодировке utf8 и таблица тоже, а данные в таблице – в кодировке cp1251.

Средствами Битрикс исправить сложно – там только SQL-запросы. Лучше phpMyAdmin или программы работы с базами данных.

Возможное решение:

1. сделать дамп базы данных
2. экспортировать таблицу каталога в той кодировке, в которой она есть
3. в любом текстовом редакторе, позволяющем менять кодировку, сохранить файл как utf8
4. очистить только эту таблицу (TRUNCATE)
5. Изменить кодировку таблицы и столбцов в utf8
6. импортировать исправленную таблицу в кодировке utf8

Естественно, все модули сайта, и админские, и пользовательские будут выводить данные в utf8